# Use templated class without template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have class like this:

```
template<size_t MAX_SIZE>
struct Buffer{
   size_t size;
   char data[MAX_SIZE]; // this must be inside the struct itself
   constexpr static size_t max_size = MAX_SIZE;
};
```

I need to be able to pass this class to function that shouldn't use template, currently I am doing something like this:

```
void process(size_t &size, char *data, size_t max_size);

int main(){
   Buffer<1024> b;
   process(b.size, b.data, b.max_size);
}
```

Is there any better way to do the same? I can think about base class, and pass by reference, but it gets too complicated to be correct.

(This is not actual code, please do not pay attention if there are syntax errors.)

Comment: you probably want to avoid the question but: why is process not allowed to use the template? what is it allowed to use and why?

Comment: good question. reason is not 100% clear for me - intuition. meditate on this I will. Seriously - I want code of process() to be in different .o file

Comment: Your intuition probably is that you do not want process to become template, as well. This needs deeper thinking: Having MAX_SIZE as template argument means that it defines the type. Consequently, process has to become template to deal with a number of different types. If Buffer should be really only exactly one type, then MAX_SIZE should not be a template argument.

Comment: @IceFire - already did it template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a wrapper-method ...

```
template<size_t MAX_SIZE>
void process(Buffer<MAX_SIZE>& buffer)
{
    process(buffer.size, buffer.data, buffer.max_size);
}
```

... and then just call ...

```
int main()
{
    Buffer<1024> buffy;
    process(buffy);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I fail to see why the called function is required to avoid use of templates.  It seems an arbitrary an unnecessary restriction.

Just provide a helper function and conversion from your templated type.

```
struct Helper
{
     size_t size;
     size_t max_size;
     char *data;  
};

template<size_t MAX_SIZE>
struct Buffer
{
    size_t size;
    char   data[MAX_SIZE]; // this must be inside the struct itself

    constexpr static size_t max_size = MAX_SIZE;

    operator struct Helper() {return Helper {size, max_size, &data[0]};};   // C++11
    //     operator struct Helper() {Helper temp(size, max_size, &data[0]); return temp;};   // pre C++11

};

void process(struct Helper);

int main()
{
   Buffer<1024> b;
   process(b);    //   or process(Helper(b))
}
```

As long as you avoid C++ specific features, the `Helper` type is also able to be passed to C.

Answer (score 1):

What about using typedef. I mean, you can use the next signature for you function: `void process(const Buffer<1024>& b);` but it is not very suitable due to template parameter declaration. If you change value to something else, you must change signature as well. To avoid this, try to use typedef. Something like this

```
typedef Buffer<1024> TBuffer;

void process(const TBuffer& buffer);

int main(){
   TBuffer b;
   process(b);
}
```

You don't need to change rest of code if you change template value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If your reasoning to not use templates is that you do not want to have non `Buffer`s passed to the function then let me tell you that this is not a problem.  You can use a template parameter for just the size like

```
template<size_t MAX_SIZE>
void process(Buffer<MAX_SIZE>& buffer)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

And now you can only pass a `Buffer` to `process`.  You can pass any size `Buffer` but it will only take `Buffer`s.

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c88db27a4281f71)</kbd>